# Multiple Databinding Error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, data-binding

I'm keep getting this error whenever I rebuild project

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Multiple binding data tags in 
C:\Users\Tai\AndroidStudioProjects\Rxjava2Practice2 - 
Copy\app\src\main\res\layout\item_movie.xml. Expecting a maximum of one.
file:C:\Users\Tai\AndroidStudioProjects\Rxjava2Practice2 - 
Copy\app\src\main\res\layout\item_movie.xml
****\ data binding error ****
```

Also sometime the `ItemMovieBinding` don't auto generate like usual but after I restart android studio it work fine again.

Here is my `item_movie.xml`, I did try to clean and rebuild or restart android studio, but nothing work at all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="result"
        type="com.example.tai.rxjava2practice2.Model.Result"></variable>
</data>
<data>
    <variable
        name="image"
        type="com.example.tai.rxjava2practice2.Model.Image"></variable>
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_MovieName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_Avatar"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@{result.title}"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ReleaseDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_Avatar"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@{result.releaseDate}"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_Avatar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@{image.imageUrl}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: where is your </layout> end tag ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should using only one data tag as below

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="result"
        type="com.example.tai.rxjava2practice2.Model.Result"></variable>

    <variable
        name="image"
        type="com.example.tai.rxjava2practice2.Model.Image"></variable>
</data>
```

Comment: nice to help. so what is your question?

Comment: My activity_main.xml don't generate ActivityMainBinding 

It also included data tab and xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
but i can't use the ActivityMainBinding, am i forget anything?

Comment: It seem not enough info to find out the root case, and I can not put more code in my comment , you should create a new question for this issue

Comment: I find the answer, just simply rename the activity_main to main_activity, and the auto generated class works fine, tks u for support :D